# Setting local variables in a django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class MeasurementParameter(models.Model):    
    tolerance = models.FloatField()
    set_value = models.FloatField()

    tol_low = None
    tol_high = None

    def tolerance_band(self):

        tol = self.set_value * self.tolerance/100

        self.tol_high = self.set_value + tol
        self.tol_low = self.set_value - tol

        print self.tol_low

        return self.tol_high, self.tol_low
```

I wish to set the calculated local variables tol_low and tol_high using the tolerance_band method.

The model is has a ManyToMany relationship with another model called Product.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    parameters = models.ManyToManyField(MeasurementParameter, related_name='measurement')

    def calc_all_tol_bands(self):

        for parameter in self.parameters.all():
            hi, lo = parameter.tolerance_band()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So in my view I attempt to calculate all tolerance bands by:

```
product.calc_all_tol_bands()
```

However if I try and get the local variables:

```
product.parameters.all()[0].tol_low
```

I get None all the time.

What do I need to do to be able to set calculated values in the MeasurementParameter model?

John.

Comment: That is logical, since your `product.parameters.all()[0]` makes a database fetch, and hence at that time `to_low` is not calculated (yet). I think it is better here to just define properties, and thus calculate these "by request". Especially since the calculations are rather simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *expected behavior*. When you evaluate

```
product.parameters.all()[0]
```

this means you make a database fetch. So Django will fetch the first of these parameters. Since the `tol_low` and `tol_high` are *not* persistent (not stored in the database), this means that it will fallback on the class attribute, which is `None`.

The calculations here, are rather simple, so I propose that you convert these to [*properties* [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#property):

```
class MeasurementParameter(models.Model):    
    tolerance = models.FloatField()
    set_value = models.FloatField()

    @property
    def tol_low(self):
        return self.set_value * (100-self.tolerance)/100

    @property
    def tol_high(self):
        return self.set_value * (100+self.tolerance)/100

    def tolerance_band(self):
        return self.tol_high, self.tol_low
```

Here we thus will evaluate the property when necessary. This is more robust: if you change the `tolerance` of an object, or the `set_value`, then the `tol_low` and `tol_high` will be different for that object. So there is no complex code in place to update the value for relevant updates. The `calc_all_bands` is not necessary either, since calculations are simply done when requested.

Note that you can not use properties in Django ORM filters, etc. In that case, you can encode the property as a query expression and annotate the queryset with these.

Comment: This worked great. Thank you. I understand a little more now.